# Pompeii house in Heinlein's "Time Enough for Love"

Tags: robert-a-heinlein

What was the actual house in Pompeii, referenced in Heinlein's *[Time Enough for Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Enough_for_Love)*, that the Boondock House on Tertius was modeled on?

Comment: Nice question, but I very much doubt we'll get a definitive answer.  Hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Is there some reason to believe it was modeled on a real house/villa?

Comment: Primarily the way it's worded when Lazarus describes it being based on photos in a museum that were also in Minervas's data banks. I've found several 2 story villas on Pompeii sites which it could be. Given Heinlein's research methods, he had something to see/read when he was writing about it.